# How to display overlapped layout in android for profile pic

Tags: android-layout, android

Hello guys i want to display user profile information inside Sliding menu like this.

[image]

So i tried this code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutTop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sliding_menu_background" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/layoutTop"
    android:background="#f47e55" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/layoutBottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" >

    <com.itrecruter.View.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/circular_image_view"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/default_profil_photo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/circular_image_view"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="XYZ PQR"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Android / iOS Developer"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But on nexus 5 and nexus 4 it look like this :-

[image]

How to solve this undergoing layout ?
Any help is appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Why did not you choose `FrameLayout` for this? As `FrameLayout` provides the exact overlapping views usecase.. http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

Comment: @BharathMg any sample?.. i tried everything now i am stuck at this position..

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/new"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <View
           android:id="@+id/layoutTop"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="120dp"
           android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/layoutBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/layoutTop"
        android:background="#f47e55" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true">

    <com.itrecruter.View.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/circular_image_view"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/default_profil_photo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/circular_image_view"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="XYZ PQR"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Android / iOS Developer"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Try this out